# how to import shell's library source file

Tags: shell

Here's my personal shell's 'head file' **tool.h**

```
#!/bin/echo Warnning! this libiary must be scourced in file!
#ostype(): define the system type in val OSTYPE
ostype(){
    osname=`uname -s`
echo $osname
}
ostype
```

When I call it directly like `./tool.h` it prints the first line that after "#!/bin/echo"

And here is my question: How can I call this function "ostype" in 'tool.h' by anoter shell script file with it's first line `#!/bin/bash`?

I don't know how to import the "head file" just like import Jquery plug-in in Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Don't use the suffix `.h` for a shell script file; `.h` is used for C and C++ headers.  Use `.sh`.

Comment: You really shouldn't name your file `tool.h`, since it isn't a C/C++ header file.

Comment: Why are you using `#!/bin/echo` for the shebang?  `#!/bin/sh` would be more sensible.

Comment: using #!/bin/echo.for I don't want to call this source file directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `.h` as the suffix and probably should use `.sh` (or possibly `.csh` if you're using a C shell derivative).

Depending on your shell, you might use the 'dot' command (POSIX, Bourne, Korn, Bash) shells, or the `source` command (C Shell, Bash):

```
. tool.sh

source tool.sh
```

These both read the script (after finding it via a PATH-like search if there's no slash in the name) as part of the current shell environment (as opposed to running it in a sub-shell).  This means that changes made by the dotted script take effect in the calling shell - which is important when defining functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can `source` it (assume this is in another file in the same directory):

```
source tool.h
```